# Generate url based on some conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create URL address based on some specific conditions. For now I have simple code in some controller's action:

```
string url ="";
if(some conditions based on data fetched from DB)
{
  url = Url.Action("action","controller"); 
}
else{
  url = some other url;
}
```

The problem is that this kind of logic will be used in a few other places. Is it posible to move it to some other class and still use the MVC Url.Action helper? Or there is another simple way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom action filter for this.the same can be used for all actions in a controller or for only particular actions in a controller.

Inside the filter

```
public class GenerateUrlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    GenerateUrl(filterContext); 
 }

 private void GenerateUrl(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    //your logic 
 }
}
```

Add this attribute above the action methods or for an entire controller.

```
[GenerateUrl]
```

This attribute will be called before the action is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write own extension to make it available globally.

```cs
public static string NewAction(this IUrlHelper helper, string action, string controller)
{
    if (some conditions)
    {
        //Manipulate however you like
        return helper.Action(action, controller, values: null, protocol: null, host: null, fragment: null);
    }
    else
    {
        //This is default action
        return helper.Action(action, controller, values: null, protocol: null, host: null, fragment: null);
    }
}
```

Usage

```cs
Url.NewAction("action","controller");
```

Don't forget to create extension in static class.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in an action filter instead of in your action.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

> An action filter is an attribute that you can apply to a controller action -- or an entire controller -- that modifies the way in which the action is executed.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible in my case because redirect conditions are based on some data retrieved from database.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class RedirectUrlAction
{
    private int value;
    public string GetActionUrl(string action, string controller, string DefaultRediretUrl, Func<int,Boolean> Condition, UrlHelper urlHrlper)
    {
        string url = "";
        if (Condition(value) == true)
        {
            urlHrlper.Action(action, controller);
        }
        else
        {
            url = DefaultRediretUrl;
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

> calling the function

```
RedirectUrlAction act = new RedirectUrlAction();

        act.GetActionUrl("value", "get", "http//:www.google.com", (x) => x % 2 == 0, Url);
```